# Google Maps API and using the distance in a calculation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I've successfully implemented the GMAPS API into my website, and have a system where a user can search for a location, and it will return the distance between that and a set location of my choosing. However, Im wondering if there is a way to take the distance it returns and use it elsewhere on the site, for calculations of delivery prices based on how far away the entered location is, etc etc.

Cheers for the help.

Comment: What do you want the distance to be used for? What trouble are you having accessing and using it "elsewhere on the site"?

Comment: @geocodezip I was planning on multiplying it by a "costpermile" variable stored in my database, but Im unsure on how to actually store the distance as a variable to be used elsewhere.

Comment: What have you tried?  What does our code to get it and use it currently look like?  How are you accessing the "costpermile" from your database? Storing the distance in a global variable (or an HTML input element) should work.  The only potential issue is the asynchronous nature of the response (you can't use the new value until it comes back from the server).